# How to create a Rectangle object in Java using g.fillRect method

Tags: java, graphics, applet, drawing, drawrectangle

I need to create a rectangle object and then paint it to the applet using paint(). I tried

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(arg,arg1,arg2,arg3);
```

Then tried to paint it to the applet using

```
g.draw(r);
```

It didn't work. Is there a way to do this in java? I have scoured google to within an inch of its life for an answer, but I haven't been able to find an answer. Please help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void paint (Graphics g) {    
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(xPos,yPos,width,height);
    g.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());  
}
```

[edit]

```
// With explicit casting
public void paint (Graphics g) {    
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        g.fillRect(
           (int)r.getX(),
           (int)r.getY(),
           (int)r.getWidth(),
           (int)r.getHeight()
        );  
    }
```

Comment: succinct and accurate

Comment: Actually, that's wrong. The `get...` methods return `double`, but the `filRect` method requires `int`....

Comment: @Marco13 Java uses auto-boxing to automatically convert between these types. 
Furthermore, in this example no loss of precision will occur since the Rectangle constructor accepts `int`s so `r.getX` and `r.getY` will always give you a double with no decimal part.

Comment: Assuming that this is a `java.awt.Rectangle`, the code does not compile, it's as simple as that. Boxing and precision are unrelated to that. The method signature simply does not match. Try it out.

Comment: @Marco13 Looks like over the last 6 years this answer has existed it no longer works. I will update my answer with explicit casting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it never worked like this. They neither changed the `fillRect` method nor the `Rectangle` class in this regard. In the best case, this may have been a copy+paste accident, but find it utterly confusing where the 14 upvotes came from...?! However, the version with the `(int)` casts will work, so this is fixed now. (I generally prefer `Graphics2D` and `g.draw(Shape)`, but that's not the point here)

Answer (score 5):

You may try like this:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Rect1 extends Applet {

  public void paint (Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect (x, y, width, height);    //can use either of the two//
    g.fillRect (x, y, width, height);
    g.setColor(color);
  }

}
```

where x is x co-ordinate
      y is y cordinate
      color=the color you want to use eg Color.blue

if you want to use rectangle object you could do it like this:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

public class Rect1 extends Applet {

  public void paint (Graphics g) {    
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(arg,arg1,arg2,arg3);
    g.fillRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
    g.setColor(color);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you HAVE to use the rectangle object, then just throw in:
g.drawRect(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());

Answer (score 0):

**Note：**`drawRect` and `fillRect` are **different.**

Draws the outline of the specified rectangle:

```
public void drawRect(int x,
        int y,
        int width,
        int height)
```

Fills the specified rectangle. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color:

```
public abstract void fillRect(int x,
        int y,
        int width,
        int height)
```